# Convenience method to convert literal value into observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have many functions that can return either a literal value or an observable.

```
function example(): Observable<string> | string {
    // ...
}
```

Everywhere that I use these functions has to check if it's an observable, and if not then convert it to an observable.

```
   let value = example();
   value = isObservable(value) ? value : of(value);
   // do work with value.subscribe(..)
```

While I can *easily* create a function to do the above. It seems *highly* likely that the RXJS library would already have such a function.

Is there a function like `toObservable()` in RXJS?

Comment: hard to guess how you want to convert to observable. let say if you have an array do you want to emit by items or as a whole array

Comment: Its not so hard to implement by yourself and  f.e. `from('The String)` will emit by character, so you might want `of` instead. I have some doubts if RxJs has it by default. `iif(() => isObservable(source), value, from(value))`